# How do I draw samples from multivariate gaussian distribution parameterized by precision in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, probability

I am wondering how to draw samples in matlab, where I have precision matrix and mean as the input argument.

I know mvnrnd is a typical way to do so, but it requires the covariance matrix (i.e inverse of precision)) as the argument.

I only have precision matrix, and due to the computational issue, I can't invert my precision matrix, since it will take too long (my dimension is about 2000*2000)

Answer (score 11):

Good question. Note that you can generate samples from a multivariant normal distribution using samples from the standard normal distribution by way of the procedure described in [the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution).

Basically, this boils down to evaluating `A*z + mu` where `z` is a vector of independent random variables sampled from the standard normal distribution, `mu` is a vector of means, and `A*A' = Sigma` is the covariance matrix. Since you have the inverse of the latter quantity, i.e. `inv(Sigma)`, you can probably do a Cholesky decomposition (see [`chol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html)) to determine the inverse of `A`. You then need to evaluate `A * z`. If you only know `inv(A)` this can still be done without performing a matrix inverse by instead solving a linear system (e.g. via the backslash operator).

The Cholesky decomposition might still be problematic for you, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Could you expand on the math of this part, "If you only know inv(A) this can still be done without performing a matrix inverse by instead solving a linear system (e.g. via the backslash operator)" so that it can be mimicked in other languages?

Comment: @NewNameStat The backslash operator solves a system of linear equations. It would be more precise than computing the inverse, but not faster.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sample from N(μ,Q<sup>-1</sup>)  and only Q is available, you can take the Cholesky factorization of Q, L, such that LL<sup>T</sup>=Q. Next take the inverse of L<sup>T</sup>, L<sup>-T</sup>, and sample Z from a standard normal distribution N(0, I).

Considering that L<sup>-T</sup> is an upper triangular dxd matrix and Z is a d-dimensional column vector,
μ + L<sup>-T</sup>Z will be distributed as N(μ, Q<sup>-1</sup>).

If you wish to avoid taking the inverse of L, you can instead solve the triangular system of equations L<sup>T</sup>v=Z by back substitution. μ+v will then be distributed as N(μ, Q<sup>-1</sup>).

Some illustrative matlab code:

```matlab
% make a 2x2 covariance matrix and a mean vector

covm = [3 0.4*(sqrt(3*7)); 0.4*(sqrt(3*7)) 7];

mu = [100; 2];

% Get the precision matrix

Q = inv(covm);


%take the Cholesky decomposition of Q (chol in matlab already returns the upper triangular factor)

L = chol(Q);

%draw 2000 samples from a standard bivariate normal distribution

Z = normrnd(0,1, [2, 2000]);

%solve the system and add the mean

X = repmat(mu, 1, 2000)+L\Z;

%check the result 

mean(X')

var(X')

corrcoef(X')

% compare to the sampling from the covariance matrix

Y=mvnrnd(mu,covm, 2000)';

mean(Y')

var(Y')

corrcoef(Y')

scatter(X(1,:), X(2,:),'b')

hold on

scatter(Y(1,:), Y(2,:), 'r')

For more efficiency, I guess you can search for some package that efficiently solves triangular systems.
```